# Why do I get different results with almost the same command in docker with MySQL?

Tags: docker

I use centos7 and  `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`

I want MySQL container's `/etc/mysql` bind mount to `/data/etc/my01` and I use the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 \
-v /data/etc/my01/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
-v /data/my01:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=25802580 --name my01 mysql
```

It's OK, the container run in the background.

But, I delete this container and create another use follow command:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 \
-v /data/etc/my02:/etc/mysql \
-v /data/my02:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=25802580 --name my02 mysql
```

When I use `docker ps`, I find this container has stopped.

I can't understand this behavior, because the principles of these two commands are almost the same.
Why do I get different results with almost the same command?
And how to correct the last command?

Comment: welcome to [so] a programmer's forum. i think your question is off-topic here (as it is really about just running a MySQL service), better ask on [sf]. However, the question as you asked it is basically un-answerable, as it lacks a lot of necessary information. you would need to at least specify what your docker image really is ("mysql" is just a name) and what the content of your data-directories is. chances are that the configuration in /data/etc/my02 is just bogus.

Comment: You should run in foreground mode and see the exact error you get. It is impossible to help your with so little info without making wild guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your second command:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 \
-v /data/etc/my02:/etc/mysql \
-v /data/my02:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=25802580 --name my02 mysql
```

The first volume definition is different than from your first container:

`-v /data/etc/my02:/etc/mysql \`
vs
`-v /data/etc/my01/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d`

There could be problems on startup of the container, e.g. if the config fails are invalid, so the container tries to boot up and then exits.

You can easily debug issues like this by running the container not in background mode (removing the -d argument):

```
docker run -p 3307:3306 \
-v /data/etc/my02:/etc/mysql \
-v /data/my02:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=25802580 --name my02 mysql
```

Then you will see the error output of your container in your console.